# $G$-torsor for topological space compared to that for sheaf of groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, sheaf-theory

I just read about the definitions about torsor of sheaf of groups and get a bit confused. 
How does the notion of $G$-torsor for a topological space compared to that of a sheaf of groups?  Is there a similar weak equivalence $\Omega B G\simeq G$ for $G$ a sheaf of group?

Why is there an equivalence $\Omega BTors(G)\simeq G$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of $G$-torsor for a topological space is the same as the sheaf-theoretic  definition, once you are familiar with the language of site.

Your desired weak equivalences exist, in which the looping need (right) derived (w.r.t. the local model structure), they follow from Jardine's *Local Homotopy Theory*, Proposition 9.26 and Corollary 9.27. I suggest you work out these as a good exercise.

Comment: Is the first equivalence not true without right derived?

Comment: I think it's still true, it's in fact a sectionalise weak equivalence, very fortunate that it's also the case in Jardine's local model structure.

Comment: I think both cases are true without right derived.  Since $BTorsG$ is $\tau$-local and the loop space functor is a right adjunction which preserves fibrant objects, right?

Comment: I think ${\rm BTor}G$ is not $\tau$-local, Jardine's result says it satisfies descent though, so to get a right derived looping (w.r.t. the local model structure), we only need apply a (functorial) sectionalise fibrant replacement to ${\rm BTor}G$. Then descent   says it has the right homotopy type.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "sectionwise fibrant replacement". (The auto-grammar-checking is very annoying.)

Comment: Now I think non-derived is fine, since Tors is a presheaf of groupoid, BTors is already sectionwise Kan, together with that it satisfies descent, we see the naive sectionwise looping has the right homotopy type.

Comment: BTorG is always projective local but how can one show that it is also injective local? (Now my question is not related to the weak equivalence) I asked because I have seen it is used that BTorG is injective fibrant somewhere

Comment: I was just using the Quillen equivalence between the projective local and injective local structure; the important thing is that the class of those simplcial presheaves satisfy descentis independent of the model structure, hence any replacement which satisfies descent—not necessarily fibrant  w.r.t. some (local) model structure—compute the  homotopy type of the derived functor; cf. Jardine's *Local Homotopy Theory*, Example 5.42.

Comment: I mean can you know that BTorsG is local injective fibrant?

Comment: No, local injective fibrant>local projective fibrant>those simplcial presheaves satisfy descent. Usually the last one—easiest to meet—is sufficient to compute homotopy types (if it's the target space, like those in RMap, RHom).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98734/discussion-between-nicky-and-lao-tzu).